# How do I fix my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on a fragment?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working on this application and I'm trying to show my "expenses" database data in my personal fragment. I have created a recycler view file to replace the default layout. I am struggling to make this work. Can anyone help with the FirebaseRecycler Adapter and the holder class? I am not able to make this work, my fragment display the default layout with no information. I have tried and follow some codes but it is not working.

here is my personal fragment where the recycler view should appear

```
package uk.brighton.ama75.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;


import java.time.chrono.JapaneseDate;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class personalFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Adapter adapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Expenses").child(currentUserID);

        recyclerView = myView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_expense);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        return myView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();



        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("expenses")
                .limitToLast(5);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PersonalExpenses> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PersonalExpenses>()
                        .setQuery(query, PersonalExpenses.class)
                        .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PersonalExpenses, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PersonalExpenses model) {


                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                holder.setAmount(model.getAmount());
                holder.setType(model.getType());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.expense_recycler, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }


   public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final View mView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        private void setDate(String date) {
            TextView mDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.date_income);
            mDate.setText(date);
        }

        private void setType(String type) {
            TextView mType = mView.findViewById(R.id.type_txt);
            mType.setText(type);
        }

        private void setDescription(String description) {
            TextView mNote = mView.findViewById(R.id.note_txt);
            mNote.setText(description);
        }

        private void setAmount(String amount) {
            TextView mAmount = mView.findViewById(R.id.amount_income);
            String stramount = String.valueOf(amount);
            mAmount.setText(stramount);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the expenses recycler view file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/expense_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_income"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6 June 2019"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Type"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/note_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/type_txt"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3
">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount_income"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0000"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the personal layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFF1F3FC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:id="@+id/expenses"
                    android:text="expense"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/expense_txt"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="000.00"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_expense"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing these two main code.

Set `adapter.startListening()` inside onStart()

Set `adapter.stopListening()` inside onStop()

Make sure to put the code before the scope end of onStart() as you are performing a lot of operations and setting your adapter above.

Comment: I have tried to add the startListening() and stopListnening() but the fragment do not recognize the adapter in the onStop method. So I try to place my Firebase outside the onStart method and it still doesn't work. The fragment seems to be asleep.

Comment: Put your firebase code in onCreate() of the fragment.
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: Hy, I have tried that and the codes do not respond.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make this work placing the code inside the oncreateView().